# Speakers buzz when plugged in laptop

Tags: battery, charger, system-sounds

I bought new laptop lenovo legion y530 a few days ago, but today I faced a problem using it.

I have 200w audio system 5 + 1 speakers which when I plug in the laptop a buzz sound appears. What confuses me is that the sounds comes only from that source ( laptop ). I do not have the same problem using my phone or any other laptop at home. Even more interesting is that I have this issue only when laptop is charging i.e. is connected to electricity.
Any ideas what may be the reason for that ?

Probably useful facts :
Laptop has metal body
Tried plugging my metal body phone and testing under the same conditions = no buzz sound
Tried different sources of electricity = still buzz sound

Comment: You have a ground loop (bad earth) somewhere.

Comment: ...or lack of earth & a cheap switch-mode power supply leaking charge

Comment: Does it make the same sound with the charger attached?  If not, it is laptop related.  May not be fixable but you might be able to filter it out with some sort of line level audio filter.

Comment: @Damon, actually the problem appears only if the charger is attached.

Comment: @DavidPostill, how am i supposed to fix that ? Thank you !

Comment: @Tetsujin, if i do not fix the problem itself but just fix it like that do i put in any risk my laptop ?

Comment: Could be the laptop charging circuit inside the laptop is the problem or the charger itself.  Try a new charger or a "ground loop isolator".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term 'ground loop' is very often misconstrued & misunderstood. In consumer electronics, where the entire building is on the same earthing point & mains voltage phase, it is almost never the correct diagnosis.

The most likely cause is that your charger doesn't even have any earth connection at all & relies on being 'double insulated' [bad term, but that's the general consumer name for it] to prevent injury & remove the necessity for it to have a compulsory earth connection.

The high frequency switch-mode supplies that you get with laptops have a leakage-tolerance that results in symptoms such as yours, or even tingling fingers when you touch the laptop casing. It's technically 'safe' & won't kill you, but you cannot actually 'fix it' without investing in a better PSU.

## Do not, under any circumstances, even consider removing the earth from any mains circuitry.

This is stupid & dangerous.

Answer (score -1):

You have a ground loop, probably where you are pluging your laptop to charge. This means that your ground connection is not really that reliable.

In order to skip out of this loop you can do one of various things:

1.- Get a extension cord without ground, or open it and pull the middle metal thingy(rail, maybe?) where the prong makes the connection.

2.- Make a shared ground circuit between the sound system and your laptop

3.- Change the cord from the laptop powerbrick to the wall socket, for one that doesn't have a ground connection.

Anyway, ground is important and you shouldn't mess with it. But white noise can drive people mad.

Cheers.

edit:

I had this one friend, who had a problem with a desktop and his beast of a sound system. There was this white noise, which was driving him nuts. We ended up gutting a powerstrip and removing the metal conections to ground. Then we plugged everything to that power strip. This did the trick, as part of the problem was maybe on the connection of the sound system to the electric outlet, as here in Chile most building do have ground connections, but sometimes the workers only route the cables but don't actually bury a ground stake.

Comment: Thank you for the answer,dmb! Actually the white sound is not a real problem for me unless i put my laptop in danger, because i barely use this one for music or something like that.

Comment: This is **bad & dangerous** advice. Removing earth is not a "fix" it is a danger. I'm aware some countries have no mandatory earthing code, they attempt to compensate "safety" by using lower voltages [110 vs 240] but that does not make it 'safer' merely slightly less likely to kill you.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yeah, that what i said in my answer. As I said, even if you have regulations, sometimes stuff like this happens. You can either make a new ground connection for the whole house, or for only that part. Or you can do that. Most of the time is safe, unless you are manipulating stuff in unsafe ways or your wiring is sketchy.

Comment: Why even suggest it? It is dangerous & stupid.

Comment: @Tetsujin Because if you have a descent Fuse system(we call it Breakers), powering an ungrounded sound system with a laptop shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Mindless optimism. Are you aware that most RCD circuit-breakers rely on measuring the leakage to earth as their trip mechanism? Old-fashioned fuses, on the other hand rely on leaking enough current for long enough to melt the wire... all the time that takes, YOU are being used as the circuit.